# sci-hub response 403 error on python request?

Tags: python, get, request

I created request to sci-hub.se by requests on python.
Server response 403 error. Actually, bot request successful after deployment. But in 1-4 hours more, request got 403 error.
I use this link: https://sci-hub.se/https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211285519301648
Could you help me how to solve it?

This is my code:

````
html_text = requests.request('GET', sci_url)```

My bot located on heroku. Telegram bot.
````

Comment: Please add more context and exact error stack

Comment: Your access to that URL is Forbidden. That's what HTTP 403 is telling you. It is likely that you'll need to provide some specific HTTP headers that *may* include authentication information (username/password etc). Unless it's private, add the full URL to your question and someone will undoubtedly figure it out

Comment: Yes. I tried to take download link from sci-hub. Just use like this: https://sci-hub.se/https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211285519301648.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I kept getting this on the main page which led me to this page :”403 Forbidden openresty/1.21.4.3 sci-hub.se”  Upon clicking the link in the Q, the page quickly loaded all but the main section, paused for a long time and then completed loading, after which the main page also loaded. I presume the site is under under frequent/heavyDDoS attack from “legitimate“ monopolists.  And this is an adverse side effect of a war of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the validity of your URL. However, this will probably give you what you need:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1'}
    (r := session.get('https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S2211285519301648', headers=headers)).raise_for_status()
    print(r.text)
```